# Failure to access image from ImageField from model to display on one of my html pages

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, imagefield

I am working on a commerce app wher a user can create a listing and also upload the image of the listing. The data is handled by a `ModelForm`:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = [
            'date_made',
            'user',
            'category',
            'is_active',
        ]
```

The `ModelForm` inherits from the `Listing` model. **Pay particular attention to the** `upload_image` **attribute**:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    NAME_CHOICES = [ 
        ('Fashion', 'Fashion'),
        ('Toys','Toys'),
        ('Electronic','Electronics'),
        ('Home', 'Home'),
        ('Other', 'Other')
    ]
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    date_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_listings', null=True)
    starting_bid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=264, default=10.00)
    upload_image= models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='name', related_name='category_listings', default=NAME_CHOICES[4][0], db_constraint=False)
    listing_category = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=NAME_CHOICES, null=True, default=NAME_CHOICES[4][0])
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

I also have tried to make some media file configurations to my app.

*settings.py*:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

*(global/project) urls.py*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views.py looks like this, im not sure if it is relevant to the problem:

```
def create_listing(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        import datetime
        listing_form = ListingForm(request.POST)
        # bid = request.POST['starting_bid']
        

        
        if listing_form.is_valid():
            bid = listing_form.cleaned_data['starting_bid']
            listing_form.save(commit=False)
            # listing_form.user = request.user
            listing_form.user = request.user
            listing_form.date_made = datetime.datetime.today()
            listing_form.is_active = True
            listing_form.category = Category.objects.get(name=listing_form.cleaned_data['listing_category'])
            
            
            listing_form.save()
            Bid.objects.create(value=bid, listing=listing_form.instance)
            return HttpResponse('Listing has been saved successfully!')
```

Lastly the html tag that i cant get to work looks like this:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{listing.upload_image}}"class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Picture not available">
```

[image: The page wont display the pictures that the users upload]

I've tried to look at other stackoverflow answers but they dont seem to solve the problem. How do I get the page to display the images?

Comment: Try changing `img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{listing.upload_image}}"` to `img src="{ {listing.upload_image.url }}"`

Comment: @raphael, that works, but there seems to be another bug in my code. When I upload an image to the Listing model from the django admin page, the image is saved and displayed correctly in my html page. However, when I try to save it from a view ```create_listing```. The image is not saved correctly. Is there a problem with my view from the above code/

Comment: Try changing `listing_form.user = request.user`, and other similar lines to `listing_form.instance.user = request.user`.